# In Azure Blob Storage what is the difference between Virtual Directory and Containers?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I want to build scalable storage but I am confused as to when you would use Virtual Directory as opposed to Containers. Which is more performant when uploading images using C# .NET Core, or if they both have their own use cases, what would they be?

I was expecting that a container would be used as below:

- PhoneImages (Container)

  - iPhone11 (Virtual Directory) then inside that virtual directory

    - iPhone11 Side Image
    - iPhone11 Rear Image

However, it occurred to me that you could use a container for each phone model as below:

- iPhone14Images
- SamsungS21Images
- GooglePixel7Images

Answer (score 2):

A virtual directory is essentially just a group of blobs with the same naming prefix. A container is more like a physical folder. You could potentially use them interchangeably but there are differences.

One key difference for your use case may be that a container name can only be 63 characters long and only contain certain characters. A blob name - including the prefix - can be up to 1024 characters and use any combination of characters. Another thing to note is that a container can be empty whereas a virtual directory can't be as it is a collection of blobs. If there are no blobs with the virtual directory prefix it effectively doesn't exist.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata

Comment: `A virtual directory is essentially just a group of blobs with the same naming prefix` - This is the best and the most concise explanation of a virtual directory I have seen till now. Thanks!

Comment: Any comments regarding performance? Is one more performant than the other?